# Add multiple constraints to a generic function definition (why must I inline)?

Tags: generics, f#

I want to add 2 constraints to my generic function. a constructor constraint and a member constraint.

```
let somefn<'T when 'T : (new : unit ->  'T) and 'T : (member Add : 'T -> unit)> v = new 'T()
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
/stdin(32,5): error FS0670: This code is not sufficiently generic. 
The type variable  ^T when  ^T : (new : unit ->   ^T) and  
                            ^T : (member Add :  ^T *  ^T -> unit) 
could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.
```

I really don't understand this error message.

Only if I change the definition to:

```
let inline somefn<'T when 'T : (new : unit ->  'T) and 'T : (member Add : 'T -> ...
```

It starts working.

Can anybody explain this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Member constraints on generic type parameters are only supported for inline definitions because the .NET type system doesn't support them, so your definition can't be compiled to a vanilla .NET generic function.  Instead, the compiler will inline a copy of your definition at each call site (e.g. to call the correct `Add` method at the call site, if your definition used it).